# onbeforeunload() is not being fired when pressing back button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, back-button

i'm implementing a message for the onbeforeunload() event, it is working fine when an user tries to refresh or abandon the page, but is not working when the users hit the back button. Any idea of what could be happening?

The code im using is this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event)
{
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page? All data that was entered will be lost.';
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the code works on this page in console with back button...

Comment: @dandavis Which page are you refering to?

Comment: Are you using a single page application by any chance?

The beforeunload event gets triggered when the window is about to unload its resources, it happens when user is navigating to another page via a Full Page Reload

One of the most important difference between SPA and multip-page websites is that the window will never unload its resources when user is navigating between different "views" in a SPA. The browser never does full-page reload unless user is hitting the "refresh" button.